# What is the false positive rate for compact block filters?

Tags: compact-client-side-block-filters

I read in the mailing list that the rate of false positives for compact block filters is small, but what is the actual rate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compact block filters encode the output scripts of both spent TXOs and created UTXOs.

[BIP158](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0158.mediawiki)  states that the *false positive rate M* is 784931. This means that for every looked up output script that’s not present in the block, there is a chance of 1/784931 that the filter produces a match (i.e. a false positive).

Under the assumption that the wallet is monitoring about 1000 output scripts, this works out to about one random block downloaded every 8 weeks (H/T Dave Harding).

The chance of true positives is 1. Any output script present in the block will always produce a match when it is looked up, i.e. the chance of false negatives is 0.

Comment: For every `scriptPubKey` you look up, if it is not present in the block, you have a chance of 1/784931 of getting a match. If it is present in the block, the chance is 1 obviously.

Comment: Thanks @PieterWuille, I have updated my phrasing.